# The image stuck in action payload too large

Tags: reactjs, node.js

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use("/", express.static("uploads"))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
```

**SignupPage.jsx**

```
 <label htmlFor='file-input'
                                className='ml-5 flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300
                                rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 cursor-pointer'>
                                    <span>Upload File</span>
                                    <input type='file' name='profile' id='file-input' accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
                                    onChange={handleFileInputChange} className='sr-only' />
                                </label>
```

I got stuck if I try to upload the profile picture on the client side with the error 413. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put `app.use(express.json())` at the end of the code, because if you run it as first it will default the limit to 1mb.

So in your case

```
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use("/", express.static("uploads"))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
app.use(express.json())
```